# Using @ControllerAdvice in multiple packages

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, exception

I have a package called 
services. Under this I have 2 other packages called service1 and service2.
There are 2 controller classes, Controller1 and Controller2 in each service package respectively.

Now, since I have created a package called exceptions and all my exception handling code goes here (that being @ControllerAdvice class and my custom exceptions). This exceptions package belongs to the service1 package.

Now the problem, the exception handling is triggered on all exceptions thrown by Controller1 (this being in the service1 package), But does not handle exceptions thrown by Controller2.

Why is this happening? Am I missing some annotation or configuration? Kindly help. Thanks!

Comment: Have you listed all of your controllers in `@ControllerAdvice(basePackageClasses = {Controller1.class, Controller2.class})`?

For reference [27.1.9 Error Handling](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-error-handling)

Comment: @PärNilsson Yes I tried this, but did not work for me

Comment: And your Controller's and ControllerAdvice are public?

Comment: @PärNilsson Yes, that's right

Comment: @liksar as you see, we're now entering a boring game of "have you done that? have you written that?, etc.", because you didn't post your code. Post all the relevant code (preferrably a complete exemple reproducing the problem), so that we don't have to guess what might be wrong.

Comment: @liksar try keeping these two under same package and check whether exception handling is triggered for `Controller2`, at least we would understand whether or not it is Package problem